# VBA Copying image to chart giving error

Tags: vba

I'm writing a code to populate a data table then take and save an image of it by calling a module someone else made.  My portion of the code is able to create the image and the sub that gets called works for creating images for other tables, but I think something is missing in my portion.  This is the for loop to cycle through different product lines and create images of their tables.

```
For i = 0 To UBound(allLines)
    Cells(bcell, 2) = Cells(product, 2)
    Cells(bcell, 3) = Cells(product, 3)
    Cells(bcell, 4) = Cells(product, 4)
    Cells(bcell, 5) = Cells(product, 5)
    Cells(ecell, 2) = Cells(product, 6)
    Cells(ecell, 3) = Cells(product, 7)
    Cells(ecell, 4) = Cells(product, 8)
    Cells(ecell, 5) = Cells(product, 10)
    Range(Cells(acell, 1), Cells(ecell, 5)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("M14").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
    myfilename = Year(Now) & " " & MonthName(Month(Now)) & " " & allLines(i)     & " Production Status Metrics" ' & ".jpg"
    EndFilePath = "C:\Users\*******\Documents\**********\TEST FILES\" &     myfilename 'edited for privacy
    Call ExportMyPicture(allLines(i), EndFilePath) 'Module: Export_Cells_to_File
    Range("A1").Select
    acell = acell + 5
    ecell = ecell + 5
    bcell = bcell + 5
    product = product + 1
Next
```

This is the sub that gets called up to the line that gives me an error

```
 Sub ExportMyPicture(SelectedLine As String, EndFilePath As String)

 Dim MyChart As String, MyPicture As String
 Dim PicWidth As Long, PicHeight As Long

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 MyPicture = Selection.Name
 With Selection
       PicHeight = .ShapeRange.Height
       PicWidth = .ShapeRange.Width
 End With

 Charts.Add
 ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=SelectedLine & " Actions" 'This line gives the error
```

The error message reads object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: What line gives you the error? We shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: The last one,
    `ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=SelectedLine & " Actions"`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to make an embedded chart. In this case the chart has a container object called a chart object which sits between the chart and the containing sheet. Rather than creating a chart and then adjusting its location, you can add it as a chart object in the target sheet. Something like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Set mySheet = Sheets(1)
    Dim PicWidth As Long, PicHeight As Long
    PicWidth = 200
    PicHeight = 100
    Dim CO As ChartObject
    Dim CH As Chart

    Set CO = mySheet.ChartObjects.Add(10, 10, PicWidth, PicHeight)
    Set CH = CO.Chart
    CH.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    CO.Activate
End Sub
```

The 4 parameters of the `Add` method are `left, top. width, height`.

Comment: I'm going to add this as a new sub to call out in my code, the other one was working fine for adding plots from other data sheets.  Thanks, I'll update as to how it works out.

Comment: The part of the Excel Object Model that deals with charts isn't very intuitive. I can usually get what I want but often need a fair amount of consulting documentation, looking at (but not copy-pasting) code from the macro recorder, etc. I find that declaring explicit variables (rather than relying on selection, activechart, etc.)  helps a lot since then you can use intellisense to help you make the right method calls.

Comment: The code you suggested is adding new charts, thanks!  I'd like to paste the existing table picture into the chart to be saved but the added code produces an error.  The lines I added are 
`With ActiveSheet`
`.pictures.copy`
`.CO.ChartArea.select.`
`.Paste`
I get an error on `.CO.chartarea.select`